# Как правильно прописывать пути к картинкам для приложений в EXPO (React Native)?

Tags: react-native, expo

Картинки находятся в папке Assets , и согласно документации Expo - https://docs.expo.io/versions/v36.0.0/react-native/images/
Вот так если прописать путь - asset:/app_icon.png  - то не работает.
 Также не работает вот такая запись - 
@expo/snack-static/assets/1.jpg   согласно этой документации https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image
Гл если путь картинки указать урлом - тогда картинки отображаются. 
Пример здесь https://snack.expo.io/@lenadgit/great-cheese-2
(на 35 строке кода - варианты подключения картинок).
Работу скрипта можно посмотреть с помощью установленного приложения Expo на телефоне - отсканировать QR код после нажатия кнопки Run http://joxi.ru/zANa0RzIvgwzR2    Картинки появляются когда поворачивать телефон.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Image source={require("../assets/images/123.png")} style={{width: 100, height: 100}}/>
```

В адресе может быть "../" два раза или более, в зависимости от глубины нахождения файла из которого ты ссылаешься на картинку. По этому сперва введи "../    --затем подожди когда интерпритатор сам представит тебе возможные варианты подолжения.
 ВАЖНО!!! картинки не отобразятся если не указать в стиле к ним ширину и высоту.

Comment: В <Image source> передаеться объект из массива. Можно передать как то так? <Image source={require(src)} style={{width: 100, height: 100}}/> (где src переменная которая берет значение из массива рандомным методом).  Но при такой записи - выдает ошибку - src is not defined

Comment: пример src объекта, с примером строки адреса можно пожалуйста?

Comment: картинки находятся в той же папке что и скрипт. Когда ввожу ../ - что-то не подставляет путь интерпретатор   http://joxi.ru/v29XQM3IZWnvnm          SRC  во View  в рендере прописан так <Image style={styles.ImgStyle} source={{ uri: this.state.src }} />

Comment: если в той же директории, то тогда "./image.png" (одна точка и слэш), либо можно сразу вбивать имя файла "source={require('image.png')}".

Comment: но source={{ uri: this.state.src }}    и  source={require('image.png')}   это разные вещи. Если require то путь к картинке которая находится в папке, а если uri: - то картинка о урлу либо передаеться объектом. В моем случае - это объект. Возможно там не в path тогда дело, или если картинка как объект то path там по другому прописывается?

Comment: Прошу прощения не посмотрел ссылку которую вы приложили. Вам нужно написать:
const arr = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg"];
.....
<Image source={require(arr[0])} style={{width: 100, height: 100}}/>

В случае если у Вас ссылка на интернет ресурс:
const arr = ["h t t p : / / server.domain/image1.jpg", "h t t p : / / server.domain/image2.jpg"];
.....
<Image source={{uri: arr[0]}} style={{width: 100, height: 100}}/>

Comment: И у вас не картинка как объект, у Вас путь на картинку в виде объекта.

Comment: если передать элемент массива в require(arr[0])- тогда выдает ошибку ReferenceError: arr is not defined   at App.render . Но и зачем передавать элемент массива если надо передать state.src. Картинка должна подгружаться любая рандомным методом.  Вы уверены что в require  можно передавать что-либо кроме статичных картинок?  http://joxi.ru/ZrJdVLzIwgV5y2

Comment: хмм, да, действительно.
Но можно сделать так:
const arr = [require("1.jpg"), require("2.jpg")];
....
<Image source={arr[0]} .....

Comment: 1) const arr = [require("1.jpg"), require("2.jpg")];  - если добавлять require в массив, в итоге был запрос от snack добавить эти картинки в package.json. Если принять запрос (согласиться) - тогда такая ошибка http://joxi.ru/4Ak83PgSoEoX4r         2)<Image source={arr[0]}  -  тут не совсем понимаю зачем передавать в массив 0, - в таком случае будет выводиться только первый элемент массива (всегда только одна и та же картинка), а надо чтобы рандомно любая